# iOS installing IPA file : app disappear at 100% with no message

Tags: iphone, ios-provisioning, ipa

Since last november, I was posting versions of my client's app on a server, by creating an IPA file.

The procedure is quite simple, just click Product => Archive then "Share" and follow the wizard...

But I changed my computer and I had to renew every provisionning profile with a certificate associated with the new laptop.

Since, when I post a new IPA app on the server, the app is being downloaded but disappear when it reaches 100%. With no message of course...

Anybody have an idea ?

PS : of course, my client's devices and mine are all referenced in provisionning profiles.

EDIT : 
I'm using an **Ad Hoc** provisioning profile, for **Wilcard** application.

EDIT 2 :
When the application disappear, i can see in device log :

```
Mar 22 16:40:29 unknown installd[8319] <Error>: entitlement 'keychain-access-groups' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Mar 22 16:40:29 unknown installd[8319] <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
```

Comment: Do you know that Apple can revoke your developer account if you use developer provisioning profile for anything else then testing? :P

Comment: My client is testing the app. And it's a release provisioning profile.

Comment: Can you see if there's anything in the console on the device after install finishes? i.e. go to organiser in Xcode with the device connected and select 'Console' from the list under the device.

Comment: It's funny, it's exactly what I was doing. See my edit.

Comment: Can you duplicate the error if you roll back to a known-good version of the application (including deployment files such as the plist)?

Comment: I can't rollback, I renewed the provisioning profiles on apple's site. And I changed my laptop...

Comment: Why do those things stop you from rolling back?  Rolling back will establish whether it's your computer configuration at fault or if it's a change you made to your project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ouf !

I finally succeeded the procedure.

I'll try to explain my mistake, for further SO users.

When you click on Archive, Share, you have this screen :[image]

The first time, I clicked on "Save for enterprise Distribution", and XCode generated a .plist file that permit an authorized user to download the app.

But for next releases, no need to generate another .plist, so just click on "save".

The problem is I changed 2 weeks ago the name of project target, which has changed the project name itself (in plist), which has changed the bundle name.

I only had to regenerate a plist file (by clicking on "save for enterprise distribution") to solve my problem.